# Append MFCCs from all audios into one csv file

Tags: python, file, machine-learning, mfcc

I am new to MFCC extraction for machine learning. Below is my code for continuously extracting MFCCs from all .wav file in one directory. What I want to achieve is that I want to calculate the mean of MFCCs from an entire audio with exact 13 coefficients, and I want to put them from all audios into one csv file accordingly.

```
for filename in os.listdir(directoryName):
    if filename.endswith('.wav'): 
        wavedata_denoised,framerate = 
        spectral_subtraction(directoryName + "/" +filename)
        mfcc_feat = mfcc(wavedata_denoised,framerate)
        print (len(mfcc_feat)) 
        fbank_feat = logfbank(wavedata_denoised,framerate)
        outputFile = resultsDirectory + "/" + os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".csv"
        file = open(outputFile, 'w+')
        features = mean_features(mfcc_feat) 
        numpy.savetxt(file, features, delimiter=",", fmt='%s')
        file.close()
```

I tried with the above code, however, it produces several different csv files not in one csv file

Comment: It also generates error with ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead

Comment: Please do not use the comment space for such kind of additional info - edit & update your question instead.